# When was the first time subtitles were used for the original target audience?

Tags: dialogue, first-appearance, subtitles

Subtitles are traditionally (and, probably, most often) used for movies that were originally made for speakers of a different language--e.g., English-language subtitles added to a movie made in Danish, for Danes. But sometimes, in recent decades, a movie or TV show will have some lines in a foreign language to the target audience, with subtitles in the target audience's language--e.g., an American movie may have a few conversations in Danish, with English subtitles.

When was the first time this--use of a foreign language, with subtitles in the target audience's language--was done?

Comment: There were subtitles in the Woody Allen movie Annie Hall, and perhaps in Play It Again Sam too. And I think that Lawrence Welk used to display the lyrics on screen to encourage singing along. Neither example involves foreign language translation, though.